# What type of cellular automata is this?

Tags: cellular-automata

So, this is kind of a long shot, but does anybody here familiar with cellular automata know what type this is? In the game, it starts as a flat pink/red and then becomes this over the course of a few seconds, and when like this it kinda just vibrates. I'm not sure what type or style of cellular automata this is though, other than the game itself is in the retro 8 bit style overall. If I'm asking this in the wrong place, I'm sorry. Looking forward to any answers!

[image]

Comment: It's probably impossible to tell from just the screenshot. From a video it _might_ be possible, though unlikely. In any case, I suspect this question would fit better on [gaming.se]. Oh, and mentioning the name of the game would be useful.

Comment: It looks like this question is referring to some kind of game played on cellular phone. The tag "cellular-automata" might mean some concept in computer science that is very different. Please clarify what kind of answer is expected. For example, could an answer that explains that cellular automaton is [class 1 cellular-automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton#Classification) be accepted, assuming it is correct?

Comment: The game is called Strawberry Cubes, and is a free game off of Itch.io. And, in regards to the tag, the answer "class 1 cellular automaton" would be the type of answer I'm looking for. I want to recreate the automata in question but I'm having difficulty figuring out what it is.

Comment: Thanks. I looked up [a gameplay video](https://youtu.be/82f16H4ArHg) and I can see at least three different CA rules acting on different parts of the game. Apparently at least one of the rules can be mutated and/or randomized, too. (When that happens, what looks like a 10 digit base-4 number shows on the screen. I'd guess that's probably a rule code of some kind, but I'm not sure how it's encoded.)

Comment: (In any case, 10 base-4 digits for a 2 state rule probably implies that each cell can have 10 distinct non-equivalent neighborhood states excluding itself. Which is a bit surprising, since a [GoL-like CA](https://www.conwaylife.com/wiki/Cellular_automaton#Life-like_cellular_automata) would have 9 distinct neighborhoods. Maybe one of the digits is redundant?)